# Uploading many documents to many specific folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload

I have 300 folders in SharePoint for each vendor. Each month I will generate 300 pdf invoices and have to upload them into each specific folder. I want to avoid manually uploading each invoice to 300 different folders. Is there a way to automate this?

The folders are named the name of the vendor. Each folder contains a column for their "ILV" number. The ILV number is also included in the name of the pdf that will be uploaded. So I was thinking maybe there is a way to problematically add the pdf to the correct folder via the vendor ILV number. But I am new to SharePoint and programming and I do not really know how to get started.

**Ex.**
**Folder Name**: Test Company
**Document to Upload Name**: 2020Jan--ILV0834
**ILV**: ILV0834

[image: Test document I have already manually uploaded]

Answer (score 0):

I made a test script using PnP PowerShell which will be helpful to you.

You may need to [install PnP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) first.

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = ""
$adminUPN=""
$Cred = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

#Get All the files which has names containing ILV
$Files=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Documents |Where-Object {$_.Name -CLike "*ILV*.txt"}


foreach ($File in $Files) {

    #Get The ILV value inside the file name
    $folder=$File.Name.substring($File.Name.IndexOf("ILV"), 7)
    
    #Get the corresponding folder using the ILV number. In my test it is the Name field, you can change it to another column name according to your needs
    $DestinationFolder=Get-PnPFolder -List "Shared Documents" |Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $folder} 
    $FolderPath="Shared Documents\"+$DestinationFolder.Name

    #Upload File to Folder
    Add-PnPFile -Path $File.FullName -Folder $FolderPath -ErrorAction Stop

    
}
```

As I am testing under the Shared Documents library, so I used it in `Get-PnPFolder` and `Add-PnPFile`. Remember to change it with your library name.